# Jupiter Notebook is crashing when I'm trying to generate UUID on large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which has details about a flow(network connection)  this is how columns look

['connection_type'(type:string), 'connection_category'(type:string), 'bytes_in', 'bytes_out', 'flow_start', 'flow_end', 'flow_id']

```
Bytes-in -> incoming bytes  
Bytes-out is -> outgoing bytes  
Flow-start -> start of the flow (in epoch)*  
Flow-end -> end of the flow (in epoch)
Flow-id  -> (is hash of client IP, server IP, client port,server port) is unique for each connection but there are instances where same IP Port combination is spawned resulting in same flow-id  
(how to know difference if its new connection or not is if flow-start != previous records flow-end) then its a new connection
```

| flow_id | flow_start | flow_end | bytes_out | bytes_in | connection_type | connection_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 1697133312 | 1697133317 | 124 | 342 | a | b |
| 123456789 | 1697133317 | 1697133342 | 345 | 0 | a | b |
| 123456789 | 1697133400 | 1697133454 | 0 | 100 | x | y |
| 123456789 | 1697133454 | 1697133499 | 200 | 200 | x | y |
| 123456789 | 1697133499 | 1697133600 | 0 | 15 | x | y |

What i want is to generate a new id which lets say U-ID will be unique if flow start is equal to flow-end of previous row which means its a new connection using same flow-id
here U-ID will be hash of flow-id and flow-start of connection

| U-ID | flow_id | flow_start | flow_end | bytes_out | bytes_in | connection_type | connection_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88888 | 123456789 | 1697133312 | 1697133317 | 124 | 342 | a | b |
| 88888 | 123456789 | 1697133317 | 1697133342 | 345 | 0 | a | b |
| 99999 | 123456789 | 1697133400 | 1697133454 | 0 | 100 | x | y |
| 99999 | 123456789 | 1697133454 | 1697133499 | 200 | 200 | x | y |
| 99999 | 123456789 | 1697133499 | 1697133600 | 0 | 15 | x | y |

This code is working for smaller data set but when i give a huge dataset J-notebook is crashing

```
import uuid
    
    def buildId(data, indices):
    flow_changed = False
    previous_flow_st = 0
    previous_flow_et = 0
    index = []
    flow_id = 0
    flow_st = 0
    flow_et = 0
    
        start_time = 0
        end_time = 0
        p = 0
        q = 0
    
        for i, j in enumerate(data):
            index.append(j[0]) if j[0] not in index else None
            flow_id = j[1]
            flow_st = j[2]
            flow_et = j[3]
    
            if i == 0:
               start_time = flow_st
               end_time = flow_et
           else:
               if flow_st == previous_flow_et:
                   # ------------------------- same flow
                    end_time = flow_et
                    if i == len(data) - 1:
                        uid = str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, str(str(flow_id) + str(start_time))))
                        indices[uid] = (index, end_time - start_time)
                elif flow_st != previous_flow_et:
                    # ------------------------- new flow           
                    # compute the uid for the previous flow
                    end_time = previous_flow_et
                    # remove the current index entry, since this does not belong to the previous flow
                    index.remove(j[0])
                    uid = str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, str(str(flow_id) + str(start_time))))
                    indices[uid] = (index, end_time - start_time)
    
                # update stuff for the new flow
                    start_time = flow_st
                    end_time = flow_et
                    index = []
                    flow_changed = True
    
            previous_flow_st = flow_st
            previous_flow_et = flow_et
        
        if flow_changed is False:
            uid = str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, str(str(flow_id) + str(start_time))))
            indices[uid] = (index, end_time - start_time)
    
    indices = {} "is dictionary key: UUID value:duration of flow"
    buildId(df_flow1\[df_flow1\['flow_id'\].isin(\[id\_\])\]\[\['index', 'flow_id', 'flow_start', 'flow_end'\]\].values.tolist(), indices)
```

Once i get "U-ID" i can merge row and cumulative bytes_out and bytes_in based on U-ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach with Pandas [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
import uuid

import pandas as pd


def get_uid(flow_id, start_time):
    """Helper function.

    Args:
        flow_id: hash of client IP, server IP, client port,server port.
        start_time: start of the flow (in epoch)

    Returns:
        hash of flow-id and flow-start of connection.

    """
    return str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, str(str(flow_id) + str(start_time))))


# Rows where flow start is not equal to flow-end of previous row 
mask = df["flow_start"] != df["flow_end"].shift(1)

df.loc[mask, "U-ID"] = df[mask].apply(
    lambda x: get_uid(x["flow_id"], x["flow_start"]), axis=1
)
df["U-ID"] = df["U-ID"].fillna(method="ffill")

df = df.reindex(columns=["U-ID"] + [col for col in df.columns if col != "U-ID"])
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

                                   U-ID    flow_id  flow_start    flow_end  \
0  9cc9e0a6-4616-3242-ac5b-e809b31787d2  123456789  1697133312  1697133317   
1  9cc9e0a6-4616-3242-ac5b-e809b31787d2  123456789  1697133317  1697133342   
2  b2cbd6bf-7bc1-382b-a89f-d34cc05b6189  123456789  1697133400  1697133454   
3  b2cbd6bf-7bc1-382b-a89f-d34cc05b6189  123456789  1697133454  1697133499   
4  b2cbd6bf-7bc1-382b-a89f-d34cc05b6189  123456789  1697133499  1697133600   

   bytes_out  bytes_in connection_type connection_category  
0        124       342               a                   b  
1        345         0               a                   b  
2          0       100               x                   y  
3        200       200               x                   y  
4          0        15               x                   y
```